# One-way functions with polynomial inverting complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, cr.crypto-security, one-way-function

Is there a trap-door-like function whose encoding complexity is polynomial time $n^{k_{1}}$ and inverting complexity(without secret key) is also a polynomial function in input length $n^{k_{2}}$ with $k_{1} << k_{2}$ (say $k_{1} = 2$ and $k_{2}$ is unconditionally provable to be bounded below by $1000$)? What are the implications of such functions if $VNP = VP$?

Answer (score 8):

Some functions are conjectured to have that property, aptly called *moderately hard*. They were first proposed in the context of spam fighting, and then found their ways into more complicated applications, such as *concurrent zero knowledge* and *timed commitment*. They usually use a function of the form $f(x) = g^{2^{2^x}} \bmod N$, first suggested by [Rivest, Shamir and Wagner](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.17.2151&rep=rep1&type=ps):

> N is a product of two large primes. Without knowing the factorization of N, the best that is known is repeated squaring - a very sequential computation in nature.

If $VNP=VP$, then factorization can be performed efficiently, and therefore we do not have to resort to repeated squaring. However, performing factorization for someone who does not know the factors of N incurs a polynomial overhead.

You may also be interested in the concept of [feebly one-way functions](http://www.springerlink.com/content/fr0l41857352q6m0/), though they are not exactly related to the question.

See the following references as well:

1. [Pricing via Processing -or- Combatting Junk Mail](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PAPERS/pvp.ps) by Dwork and Naor.
2. [Moderately Hard Functions: From Complexity to Spam Fighting](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.78.2923&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Naor.
3. [Concurrent Zero-Knowledge: Reducing the Need for Timing Constraints](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/zk/DS.ps) by Dwork and Sahai.
4. [Timed Commitments](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.108.7127&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Boneh and Naor.

Comment: Thank you. Do they break down if $VNP = VP$?

Comment: @v s: Sorry, forgot to mention that. See the edited answer.